# Prove $m(x+y)=mx+my$, $x,y\in R$,$R$ is a ring, $m\in \mathbb{Z}$.

Tags: ring-theory

I want to prove this by cases. 
Case 1) $m\in\mathbb{N}$. 
Base: let $m=1$. Then, $m(x+y)=1(x+y)=1\cdot x+1\cdot y$
Induction: Assume $m(x+y)=mx+my$, show $(m+1)(x+y)=(m+1)x+(m+1)y$
$(m+1)(x+y)=mx+my+x+y=(m+1)x+(m+1)y$,
Does it make sense? 
I also need help with $m=0$. 
If $m=0$, then, $0(x+y)=0x+0y$ (?) I am not sure how to proceed..
Please help!

Comment: I think that you talk about modules of rings. If you don't know what modules are,just think that if the ring is commutative in the act of $+$,($a+b=b+a$) then this is O.K.

Answer (score 1):

Once we are given that the operation $+$ of $R$ is *commutative* and *associative*, we can prove the statement, induction works, and the formulas you wrote do it:
$$(m+1)(x+y)=mx+my+x+y$$
Associativity is used when we omitted the parentheses (there are $2m+2$ entities on the right hand side, though $+$ is usually defined as a '*binary* operation'), and commutativity is used in the exchange
$$\overbrace{y+y+y+\dots+y}^m+x = x+\overbrace{y+y+y+\dots+y}^m\,.$$
For $m=0$, we arrive to $0=0+0$, that trivially holds. (Or are you asking, why $0\cdot x=0$ in a ring for every element $x\in R$?)

And, what's left? Negative $m$'s. If $m<0$, use this for $n:=-m$ which is positive.

Answer (score 1):

By definition of integer multiples (for $m\ge0$)
\begin{gather}
0x=\textbf{0}\\
(m+1)x=mx+x
\end{gather}
so the base of the induction is obvious:
\begin{gather}
0(x+y)=\textbf{0}\\
0x+0y=\textbf{0}+\textbf{0}=\textbf{0}
\end{gather}
where $\textbf{0}$ is the zero of $R$ (just not to make confusion).

Now the inductive step: suppose $m(x+y)=mx+my$. Then
$$
(m+1)(x+y)\overset{*}{=}m(x+y)+(x+y)\overset{\mathrm{I}}{=}
mx+my+x+y=
mx+x+my+y\overset{*}{=}(m+1)x+(m+1)y
$$
where $*$ denotes where the inductive definition is used, I where the induction hypothesis is applied. One also uses associativity and commutativity of $+$ in $R$, of course.

You now can complete for $m<0$ by observing that $mx=(-m)(-x)$ (by definition, when $m<0$).

The fact that $R$ is a ring is not relevant: just an abelian group does as well.